# DOM node recurssion

Tags: javascript, dom

so i have a basic recursion function working, but i want to append x number of of children nodes to the current parent.. but the for loop in my recursive function doesn't seem to append any more than 1 child node to it's current parent. here's a js bin of my code: any help greatly appreciated! http://jsbin.com/bihuvotupe/1/edit?html,js,output

```
function populate(parent, n){
    // loop and append
    if(n === 0){
        return;
    }else{
        n--;
        var child = boxHelper("40%", "40%");
        for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            console.log(i);
            parent.appendChild(child);

        }
        populate(child, n);
    }
}

var mother = boxHelper("600px", "600px");
document.body.appendChild(mother);
populate(mother, 4);



// makeNodeRefs(callender);


function boxHelper(height, width){
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.style.height = height;
    element.style.width = width;
    //element.style.background = colour;
    element.style.float = "left";
    element.style.margin = "5px";
    element.style.border = "2px solid black";
    element.style.borderRadius = "3px";
    // element.classList.add("inflate");
    return element;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild - at the very least, read the top two paragraphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single node can only be in one place in the DOM. Your code creates a single node and then tries to append it to several different places. The node will end up in the last place.

Move the call to that `boxHelper()` function *inside* the `for` loop.

Comment: hmm, there's another issue now. . the child nodes are only appending to the last parent not all.. any suggestions? i think this a tweak i need to make in the recurssion function

Answer (score 2):

You aren't creating 4 new children if your `for` loop. You are only creating the one and trying to append it to the `parent`.

http://jsbin.com/suhukiviqi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: http://jsbin.com/weqagobiwa/1/edit?html,js,output   gahhhhh.. how did i miss this. thx so much.. it's doing what i expect now.